# How can we show that $(1-e^{-x})/x$ goes to $1$ when $x$ to $0$?

Tags: analysis

$\lim\limits_{x\to0}(1-e^{-x})/x=1$. By using epsilon-delta, can we show this?

Comment: This can be reconnected to a notable limit. But its proof is not a trivial epsilon-delta issue.

Comment: What is your definition of $e^{x}$?

Comment: e is exponential

Comment: $e^{-x}=1-x+\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^3)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the definition of the derivatve. Let $f(x)=-e^{-x}$. Then
$$
      \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{-e^{-1}+1}{x}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(0+x)-f(0)}{(0+x)-0}=f'(0)= e^{-x}|_{x=0}=1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $e^y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{y^n}{n!}}$, simplify $(1-e^{-x})/x$ to see that the limit is 1.